# Could not find 'bundler'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I installed ruby and bundler but when I run bundle command I get error:

```
[jenkins@localhost secure_gate]$ bundle
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
[jenkins@localhost secure_gate]$
```

Is there a way to save this issue?

Comment: Can you paste the output of "gem list | grep bundler"?

Comment: Have you install `bundler`? `gem install bundler`?

Comment: Are you using rbenv or rvm?

Comment: If your Ruby isn't installed correctly it might not have the `bundle` command in your `PATH` environment variable. This makes it appear to be missing.

Answer (score 4):

Installing bundler would be a good idea :

```
gem install bundler
```